# how kubelet calculate nodefs,imagefs? Then evict a Pod

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

How can I know kubelet will check which folders or any restful api I can invoke to know the current usage of nodefs and imagefs, and free usage?

```
  --eviction-hard=memory.available<200Mi,nodefs.available<5%,imagefs.available<5% \
  --eviction-soft=memory.available<500Mi,nodefs.available<10%,imagefs.available<10% \
  --eviction-soft-grace-period=memory.available=2m,nodefs.available=240h,imagefs.available=240h \
```

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes get that info from a container engine, it most cases - docker. It do not check any folders or files, it get info on filesystem level.

To get that data, you can use [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io) together with [Node Exporter](https://github.com/prometheus/node_exporter) or [CAdvisor](https://github.com/google/cadvisor).